# Error when applying sample/class weights to fit generator

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using a tf.keras.Model fit_generator (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/Model#fit_generator)  to feed batches of data to a model. According to TensorFlow Documentation, the fit generator should be able to accept size 2 (inputs, targets) or 3 (inputs, targets, sample_weights) tuple. We have the size 2 working, but we have unbalanced classes, so I have determined sample weights. When the fit generator returns a size 3 tuple, I get the error:
”tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Can not squeeze dim[0], expected a dimension of 1, got [batch_size]"

I am using tensorflow 1.12

Loss Function is tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy

Comment: Could you add some of your code and datasets?